# Rounded Corners Are Way To Sharp and Ridged

Tags: cycles-render-engine, edges

I'm trying to render some product images for my app with a model of an iPhone. During rendering, I've realized that thr corners of the device are WAY to sharp and ridged. As you know, an iPhone's corners are smooth and round. What could I do to fix this? I attached some images to show the issue. [image: Image of the iPhone] [image: A close up picture of the corners of the iPhone] I am using Cycles.

Comment: Hi, did you try using a subsurface modifier?

Comment: @m.ardito Hello! I'm an app devloper, and I'm VERY new to rendering and modeling and those things. Can you explain what this means? Thank you!

Comment: @m.ardito Wait, nevermind. I figured it out! Thank you!